# How to map over an array that is fetched using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am working on a chat-app and is trying to make a fetch using axios for the first time. I have succeded in making the fetch because I see the array from the url when I console.logging it. However I want to map over all the messages in the array and display them for a user. But I am doing something wrong so the mapping dosent work. Can someone help me to see why?

This is my code (I belive that its the map-function that is creating the problem):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'


export const GetMessages = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState([]);
  const [userMessage, setUserMessage] = useState([]);

  const fetchResponse = async () => {
    try {
      const getResponse = await axios.get(
      'http://167.172.108.61/?storage=camilla_lofroth'
    )
    console.log(getResponse)
    setUserMessage(getResponse)
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Error')
    }
    return[]
  }  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResponse()
  }, [])

  console.log(userMessage)

  return (
    <div>
      {userMessage.map(message => (
        <p>{message.message}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
  }
```

Comment: What isn’t working ? Is message definitely an object with message inside?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the response in the array is object which make React fail to render. The 3rd to 5th items.

```
[
    {
        "message": "hej test"
    },
    {
        "message": "hej test",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "message": {
            "mess": "Hi",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "message": {
            "mess": "Hi",
            "status": true
        }
    },
    {
        "message": {
            "mess": "Hi",
            "status": true
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have message as an object within the array. You must check if its an object and then render the required field

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'


export const GetMessages = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState([]);
  const [userMessage, setUserMessage] = useState([]);

  const fetchResponse = async () => {
    try {
      const getResponse = await axios.get(
      'http://167.172.108.61/?storage=camilla_lofroth'
    )
    console.log(getResponse)
    setUserMessage(getResponse)
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Error')
    }
    return[]
  }  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResponse()
  }, [])

  console.log(userMessage)

  return (
    <div>
      {userMessage.map(message => (
        <p>{message.message !== null && typeof message.message === 'object'? message.message.mess: message.message }</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you use axios, the data returned is inside of an object called data. 
Just like like with the fetch API where you have to add `.json()` to the response, you also have to destructure the data out of axios response.

In your case, it should be something like this

```
const fetchResponse = async () => {
    try {
      const getResponse = await axios.get(
      'http://167.172.108.61/?storage=camilla_lofroth'
    )
    Const data = await getResponse.data
    Console.log(data)
    setUserMessage(data)
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Error')
    }
    return[]
  }
```